# FFMpeg doesn't have tools/zmqsend

Tags: raspbian, ffmpeg

We are trying to use zmqsend (it's part of the ffmpeg repository) to communicate with a ffmpeg instance. On Raspbian, ffmpeg is configured with --enable-libzmq, and libzmq-dev is installed, but zmqsend is not found. How to get it, besides by rebuilding ffmpeg?

Comment: ffmpeg documentation states `Look at tools/zmqsend for an example of a zmq client which can be used to send commands processed by these filters` - it's an example - you have to compile it yourself, you dont' need to compile all of ffmpeg yourself to compile that example code

Comment: @JaromandaX We've tried that, you do need all of ffmpeg. Trying to compile it by itself gives gazillions of linker errors.

Comment: if you install the appropriate `dev` packages then you dont' need to compile ffmpeg

Comment: @JaromandaX Which `dev` packages, exactly?

Comment: i.e. since zmqsend refers to libavutil, start with libavutil-dev

Comment: the fact that you get linker errors is interesting though - that suggests you have the headers that come with the `dev` packages, but not the libraries, e.g. I can't even get past `"fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory"` - so you're doing better than me

Comment: I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zmqsend can indeed be compiled independently. You need libzmq3-dev (not libzmq-dev) and libavutil-dev.

```
cd FFmpeg/
./configure
cd tools/
gcc -o /where/you/want/zmqsend zmqsend.c -I.. `pkg-config --libs --cflags libzmq libavutil`
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.